# How can I document the pattern a string param in JSDoc must match?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Is it possible to make a jsdoc like the following?

```js
/**
 * Does something with an alphanumeric string
 * @param {string/^[a-z0-9]+$/i} the string that must be alphanumeric
 * /
```

I can't see anything on the [types page for JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html), but I've found that site difficult to navigate before and I couldn't find a third party library, making me think JSDoc come with this?

Is this possible without pulling in external libraries?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying do generate documentation based on your docstrings?

Comment: @LouisbBoucquet I'm trying to hint at future developers what I mean by 'must be \<pattern>` especially in the case it's not as simple as just 'alphanumeric' (even then, this JSDoc pattern would explicitly forbid accented characters for instance).

Comment: Just put the regex in the textual description of the parameter. There's no tool that would execute it anyway. Or are you using a typechecker?

Comment: @Bergi putting it into the description would definitely work, but in the same way you can specify parameters are optional or non-nullable etc in the type part of the JSDoc, it would be *nice* to be able to specify patterns in a similar way. I'm not expecting it to be enforced (which is what I suppose you mean by executing it), and I'm not using a type checker.

Comment: I guess if you don't care, you can put anything in the type annotation. A regex is not a valid type expression, as documented on the jsdoc page you linked, but "*If JSDoc determines that a type expression is invalid, it will display an error and stop running. You can turn this error into a warning by running JSDoc with the --lenient option.*"